# cakePHP: Can't connect to MSSQL datasource

Tags: php, sql-server, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I can't connect to a mssql database server using theese settings.
I get this error:

Fatal error: Call to undefined method DboSource::connect() in /home/websites/CakeShare/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php on line 143

do i have to do something with my server?

```
            $this->db_data['test'] = array(
                'driver' => 'mssql',
                'persistent' => false,
                'host' => 'test.test.com',
                'login' => 'login',
                'password' => 'pass',
                'database' => 'testdb',
                'prefix' => ''
            );
```

Answer (score -1):

in /app/config/core.php
you can set the debug level from 0 to 2, please change the error level to 2 and give the ouptut.